# Chrome/Firefox difference with negative margin bottom percentage

Tags: css, height, percentage

I have a difference of box sizing interpretation between webkit and Firefox using height 100% on a parent.

HTML:

```
<header>
  Lorem ipsum dolor amet
</header>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="content">
    My background depends on my ancestor sibling
  </div>
</div>
<div class="red">
  <p class="white">
  Amet ipsum dolor
  </p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
header {
  height: 150px;
  background: #fff;
}
.red {
  background: red;
  padding: 6em 0;
}
.content {
  background: rgba(28,28,28, .3);
  margin-bottom: -100%;
}
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  height: 100%;
}
p.white {
  background: #fff;
  width: 70%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

JS fiddle here https://jsfiddle.net/m1fobvwv/

Result on Chrome (expected):
[image: chrome margin bottom percentage]

Wrong result on FF:
[image: firefox margin bottom percentage]

Comment: Is this a question or a bug report?

Comment: This is a question, I would like a workaround even if it is a bug, I think the bug is reported here https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=885664 but not sure

Answer (score 0):

A colleague of mine found a workaround:

Add `position: absolute; width: 100%;` to `.content`

Updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/m1fobvwv/3/